# Term describing behavior of high-margin, capitol-intensive companies in an industry with declining available resources

Tags: macroeconomics, definition, nonrenewable-resources

I am searching for the term that is used to describe the behavior for firms and companies that are often high-margin and capitol-intensive, existing within an industry where the principle resource is not only limited, but significantly declining to the point where the industry will at some point cease to exist as a viable industry.

Often such firms will diversify their holdings to reduce their exposure when facing such decline, but some do not. Instead, depending on the *specifics* of the firms, companies and the industry, some may behave differently, due perhaps to such factors as (1):

- Barriers to asset divesture due to the assets unique and distinctive
  nature.
- Shareholder demands for large payouts in the form of dividends and
  stock buybacks.
- Excessive exposure to debt acquired during periods of profitable earnings growth, coupled with a desire to avoid default.

Some entities in fact may exhibit a doubling-down on the removal of the declining resource, possibly even expanding their efforts to retrieve what remains of the finite and declining resource.

Worth noting is the behavior some firms and companies display toward the end of a product life cycle. Typically capitol-intensive firms and companies may conduct themselves as *cash cows*, able to collect economic rents for the services they provide while themselves making little, if any, new asset investment going forward. That is ***NOT*** the scenario I am referring to or thinking of.

Instead, I am referring to the behavior of those firms and companies who shun the *cash cow* model. Despite at least some realization that resource limitations available to their industry clearly indicate the end to their product life cycle, such firms and companies forge ahead with increased investment, not unlike horses heading for the finish line in the Kentucky Derby at Churchill Downs, or the Belmont Stakes, who if they win, will receive the lion's-share of the prize-money winnings.

In reality, however, the ending for such a race can be quite unexpected.

Any thoughts on what may be the appropriate term or terms for such behavior, would be greatly appreciated.

(1) See [The Little Book of Valuation](https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Eadamodar/New_Home_Page/littlebook/decliningcompanies.htm).